# How to disable moving files to Trash in Krusader in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, krusader

By pressing F8 in Krusader I've got 'Do you really want to move this item to Trash?'. How to avoid this message? I'd delete the files immediately. Right click is OK to delete files.

Answer (score 0):

Several settings are available in Krusader. They are easily found under Settings -> Configure Krusader...

- Under "General" you can choose if F8 moves the file to trash or deletes it directly.
- Under "Advanced" you can choose if you want a confirmation before deleting or not.